# how to stop CLion from passing extra options to cmake

Tags: cmake, clion

The title sums it up.

I have this in the menu:
[image: CLion menu]

and yet the call used is `/opt/clion/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-10 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-10 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_DEPENDS_USE_COMPILER=FALSE -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /some/path`

Is there a switch I can use so it just does `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE /some/path` or better yet, nothing at all (when you put nothing in the box, defaults are plugged in).

Comment: CLion passes additional parameters because it needs to **integrate** with the configured project. Actually, these parameters shouldn't harm your project. As hint for the "CMake options" suggest, you may redefine generator with `-G` option. Also there are separate fields for C and C++ compilers, which affects on `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` variables.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I understand this but i want to define everything in CMakeLists.txt and not using options.

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to define in `CMakeLists.txt` instead of that "default" options? It is impossible to set generator in `CMakeLists.txt`. Setting a compiler inside `CMakeLists.txt` is possible, but that would break integration with CLion. (And setting a compiler in `CMakeLists.txt` is not recommended). It is unlikely that you want to set `CMAKE_DEPENDS_USE_COMPILER` in the `CMakeLists.txt`. But if you want that, then you could try: this would replace the value passed in the command line, and probably do not break CLion integration.